# makefile: syntax error near unexpected token `,'

Tags: makefile

I did not succeed to fix the issue while executing the following code:

```
%.o: %.c 
if [ $(notdir $<) = file1.c ]; then \
    echo "  >>  $(notdir $<) is excluded"; \
else\ 
    ifneq ($(FLAG1),)
        $(run_function1)
    endif
    ifneq ($(FLAG2),)
        $(run_function2)
    endif
fi
```

The issue is the following:

```
 if [ file2.c = file1.c ]; then \
 echo "  >>  file2.c is excluded"; \
 else\
 ifneq (,)
 /bin/sh: -c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
 /bin/sh: -c: line 4: ` ifeq (,)'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Shell and Makefile syntax in the recipe. Keep in mind the recipe is passed to the shell pretty much un-modified except for `$()` variable expansions (i.e.: the `ifneq` and similar Make conditionals are not expanded if they are indented). See especially the first paragraph and 4th bullet of the documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html

What you meant to say is something like this, but this does not work due to the `\` line continuation subsuming the subsequent `ifndef`/`endif` (ideas anyone?):

```
%.o: %.c 
    if [ $(notdir $<) = file1.c ]; then \
        echo "  >>  $(notdir $<) is excluded"; \
    else \
ifneq ($(FLAG1),)
        $(run_function1); \
endif
ifneq ($(FLAG2),)
        $(run_function2); \
endif
    fi
```

The conditional Make function should still work:

```
%.o: %.c 
    if [ $(notdir $<) = file1.c ]; then \
        echo "  >>  $(notdir $<) is excluded"; \
    else \
        $(if $(FLAG1),,$(run_function1);) \
        $(if $(FLAG2),,$(run_function2);) \
    fi
```

Or possibly using shell conditionals is clearer:

```
%.o: %.c 
    if [ $(notdir $<) = file1.c ]; then \
        echo "  >>  $(notdir $<) is excluded"; \
    else \
        if [ -n $(FLAG1) ] \
            $(run_function1); \
        fi \
        if [ -n $(FLAG2) ] \
            $(run_function2); \
        fi \
    fi
```

Comment: As in the other question, you can't use `ifneq` unless `FLAG1` and `FLAG2` are set globally: if they're specific to this target it won't work.  Also, the definition of `run_function1` / `run_function2` could make a big difference--if they contain make functions they'll get run regardless of the value of `FLAG1` and `FLAG2` if you use the second option.

Comment: @Geza Lore The first proposal generates an issue that an "endif" is missing at the end of the makefile"

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example please?

Comment: %.o: %.c 
 if [ $(notdir $<) = file1.c ]; then \
  echo "  >>  $(notdir $<) is excluded"; \
 else \ 
ifneq ($(flag1),)
  $(run_flag1); \
endif
ifneq ($(flag2),)
  $(run_flag2); \
endif
 fi